# coffeeescript: how to declare private function that can be used from within Array.reduce?

Tags: javascript, arrays, coffeescript, scope, hoisting

The main objective is to filter duplicate items from an array by any given property. The solution I'm trying to use is in js @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/31194441/618220

I tried to implement it in coffeescript. It is all good, except the scoping of the functions. I don't want **_indexOfProperty** function to be called from outside - since it is useless in all other contexts. But if I make it *private* (by removing @ in declaration), I cannot call it from within ***inputArray.reduce***

My coffee code looks like this:

```
Utils = ->
    @filterItemsByProperty= (inputArray,property)=>
        if not _.isArray inputArray
            return inputArray
        r = inputArray.reduce(((a,b,c,d,e)=>
                if @._indexOfProperty(a,b,property) < 0
                    a.push(b)
                a
            ),[])
        r

    @_indexOfProperty= (a,b,prop) ->
        i = 0
        while i< a.length
            if a[i][prop] == b[prop]
                return i
            i++
        -1

    return

window.utils = Utils
```

here's how I invoke it from other places:

```
App.utils.filterItemsByProperty(personArray,"name")
```

And right now, anyone can do this as well:

```
App.utils._indexOfProperty(1,2,3)
```

How to modify the coffee to stop this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please remove the '@', and this time define a local variable "indexOfProperty" within filterItemsByProperty scope and assign to it "_indexOfProperty" (that way you can use "indexOfProperty" within reduce())?

```
@filterItemsByProperty = (inputArray, property) ->
    indexOfProperty = _indexOfProperty
    if !_.isArray(inputArray)
      return inputArray
    r = inputArray.reduce(((a, b, c, d, e) ->
      if indexOfProperty(a, b, property) < 0
        a.push b
        a
      ), [])
    r
```

Answer (score 2):

Just don't put `_indexOfProperty` on `this` / `@` and it won't be visible:

```
Utils = ->
    _indexOfProperty = (a,b,prop) ->
        i = 0
        while i< a.length
            if a[i][prop] == b[prop]
                return i
            i++
        -1

    @filterItemsByProperty= (inputArray,property)=>
        if not _.isArray inputArray
            return inputArray
        r = inputArray.reduce(((a,b,c,d,e)=>
                if _indexOfProperty(a,b,property) < 0
                    a.push(b)
                a
            ),[])
        r

    return

window.utils = Utils
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, and I'm surprised. As already mentioned in the question, I know that removing @ will make the function private. But I'm unable to figure out why I could not access it from within .reduce earlier today? Will have to check tomorrow.

Comment: @MrClan sorry, I must have read over it. Probably you still had the `@` symbol in your reducer function or you might have had a typo :)